# How to use like query for my problem where i have to select values from comma seperated data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select only one record from my table where RoleId is 2. The roles of user stored in comma separated data. What I have tried so far is

```
SELECT TOP 
    1 USR_ID 
FROM 
    UserDetail 
WHERE 
    Client_Id=@ClientId 
AND 
    ((USR_Role LIKE '%,2,%') 
OR 
    (USR_Role LIKE '%2%') 
OR 
    (USR_Role LIKE '%2,%') 
OR 
    (USR_Role LIKE '%,2%'))
```

But it is not working properly. In one case it is not selecting where the user role id is 2. [it is selecting the user where role is like shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjh0f.png).

How do I make my query to select only user where role is 2.

Comment: use select *from string_split('12,23,28',',')

Comment: Please specify the version of sql-server.

Comment: @AjayGupta sql-server 2014

Comment: you can use CHARINDEX to find ,2, like this : where CHARINDEX(',2,',USR_Role ,0) > 0

Comment: Both @Josaf Biehler and deeppatel answers worked for me. but i am choosing deep patel answer as accepted because i find it more easy and clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TOP 1` and a WHERE clause to return only a single row for the criteria you specified:

```
select TOP 1 USR_ID 
from UserDetail 
WHERE Client_Id=@ClientId AND (',' + USR_Role + ',') LIKE '%,2,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because you use top 1 or space between ",". You can Simply modify your query like this

```
select TOP 1 USR_ID 
from UserDetail 
WHERE Client_Id=@ClientId AND 
(replace(USR_Role, ' ', '') LIKE '2,%' or 
 replace(USR_Role, ' ', '') LIKE '%,2,%'
 replace(USR_Role, ' ', '') LIKE '%,2'
)
```

or like this:

```
select TOP 1 USR_ID 
from UserDetail 
WHERE Client_Id=@ClientId AND replace(',' + USR_Role + ',', ' ', '') LIKE '%,2,%'
```

Comment: you can check above what i have tried. your answer will also select record where role = 12 and role = 23.

Comment: Try to remove top 1 for check if value are into result

Comment: result is  containing records where Role is not equal to 2.  I want to only select the user/users where role=2

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
create table asd (
  role nvarchar(255)
  )

  insert into asd (role) values('2')
  insert into asd (role) values('2,3')
  insert into asd (role) values('23')
  insert into asd (role) values('1,2,3')


  SELECT trim(role) FROM (select ' ' + role + ' ' as role from asd) as t WHERE role like '%[^013456789]2[^013456789]%'
```

Comment: But please be aware of that using a `LIKE` search with wildcard at the beginning will force a full scan. So if you have many users, please rework your schema.

Comment: i have edited the answer. The first example did not work as expected. Now it should do what you want. The pattern `[^]` matches exactly one character and thus can not match `2` so we need to handle the special cases on our own

Comment: Yo, it is working bro. Thanks ! can you please explain me the first condition the one with  (wildcard).

Comment: @MohitLohani The first condition ensures that only the role ,2, is selected. In SQL Server you can use several patterns that are a bit like regex. But provide only a very small subset of the power of regex. In this case `[^...]` matches everything that is not between the brackets.

Comment: @MohitLohani Lol, I see that the following will work also and does not require the pattern: `SELECT * FROM asd WHERE role like '%,2,%' or role like '2,%' or role like '2'`. Not sure if my answer is the best one as it only lists all possibilities that can occurr.

Comment: @MohitLohani see my edited answer. using the subselect ensures that there is always at least one char before and one after the role and thus one pattern is enough to catch all cases

Comment: `%[^...]2[^...]%` matches everything that is anything not followed by the numbers in brackets. The same holds for the right side.

Comment: brother could not able to execute your latest edit to as per my requirement and now using your first answer because all i need is to check all possibilities of user role=2.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the string and using `cross apply`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 USR_ID from UserDetail 
cross apply
(Select B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(USR_Role,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as n
Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i))V(value) where V.value=2
and Client_Id=@ClientId
```